# MySQL Duplicate entry '16777216' for key 1 Error

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1062

I have a MySQL database that is populated via a C# application, mass uploading records on the scale of 100+ million records.  After these records are imported, further analysis and other scoring tools are used on the data.  When I choose a smaller subset of data, the records get in fine, however, when I use the full dataset, once record #16777216 is reached, this error occurs.  Before I had unique primary settings in place, duplicate ID records were being created here and there, but the data was all getting in.  However, with dup records in place, futher processing was producing incorrect results.

My question is simple, has anyone heard of this problem before, and if so, what is going on?  Is this a bug in my version of MySQL?  I am running MySQL 5.0.67 on Windows XP.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: 16777216 is the maximum number of values in a 24 bit integer. What is the size of the value you're using in the PRIMARY and UNIQUE cols?

Comment: the primary key field is a BIGINT primary key not null unsigned auto increment.

Comment: i find it incredibly coincidental that 16777216 would be the record # that keeps failing when this is a very specific datatype related # but I can't find evidence anywhere of this issue.

Comment: also, i was originally seeing this problem when the datatype was just INTEGER but that also allows for more than 16777216 records.  Note, before this was set as a primary key, records WERE getting in there, just dups started to appear at random times after it got past record ID 16777216.  It sounds totally like a bug, but I can't find any evidence of this bug showing up anywhere.  If it was some type of known bug that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

just curious...

any particular reason you're not using load data infile to populate your tables ?

if you need to process data in your application before loading you can still do that but output to csv file instead of calling a sproc 100 million times. load data infile will be much faster !!

see here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

do you really need a bigint unsigned primary key (8 bytes) vs. unsigned integer (4 bytes) with max value of 4294967295 (4 billion)

see here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

just thoughts...

Comment: if i am doing the load infile how is this going to compare when the load goes from db inserts over and over again to I/O of writing and reading the CSV created?  i had suggested this very action to another developer and he said there were lots of performance issues originally with the I/O side of things... thanks!

Comment: Creating a .csv file with 100 million++ rows wont take long but you could split it into 10 files of say 10 million rows then use load data infile to load each one separately. I would imagine your current method of loading takes several hours if not more. Using your app to generate 1 or more .csv files then bulk loading you'd be all done in 20 mins. Some helpful tips here http://pastie.org/1348793 - hope this helps.

Comment: current method takes absolutely forever.  i will definitely look to make this change, thank you!

Comment: i have the CSV working from the mysql prompt but i can't figure out how to call this correctly in the .NET code.  Any help is appreciated, thanks

calling ExecuteNonQuery on the full script just errors out

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there isn't a `MEDIUMINT` involved somewhere? Run `show create table` on the table that's showing this problem.

Comment: Here are the results of this split into 2 comments:

Comment: metrics | CREATE TABLE `metrics` (
  `classification` int(11) default NULL,
  `edit_distance` int(11) default NULL,
  `edit_goodness` float default NULL,
  `shorter_name_len` int(11) default NULL,
  `spatial_distance` float(30,2) default NULL,
  `spatial_precision_deg` float(30,5) default NULL,
  `spatial_goodness` float(30,5) default NULL,

Comment: `feature_type_distance` double default NULL,
  `score` float(30,3) NOT NULL,
  `metrics_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ch_unique_feature_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `ch_unique_name_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `ref_unique_feature_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `ref_unique_name_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `set_id` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`metrics_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16777217 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------

Comment: @Dan: I don't see anything problematic here. Maybe there's something wrong in the C# code that's feeding the database.

Comment: C# call:                                     sqrstart = "call inmetrics (";
                                    sqrest = "?Classification, ?EditDistance, ?EditGoodness, ?ShorterNameLen, ?SpatialDistance, ";
                                    sqrest1 = "?SpatialPrecisionDeg, ?SpatialGoodness, ?FeatureTypeDistance, ?MetricsID, ";
                                    sqrest2 = "?ChUniqueFeatureID, ?ChUniqueNameID, ?RefUniqueFeatureID, ?RefUniqueNameID, ?SetID)";

Comment: SqlDbHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(sqrstart + sqrest + sqrest1 + sqrest2, paramClassification, paramEditDistance, paramEditGoodness, paramShorterNameLen, paramSpatialDistance, paramSpatialPrecisionDeg, paramSpatialGoodness, paramFeatureTypeDistance, paramMetricsID, paramChUniqueFeatureID, paramChUniqueNameID, paramRefUniqueFeatureID, paramRefUniqueNameID, paramSetID);

Comment: stored procedure: CREATE DEFINER=`featurematch`@`%` PROCEDURE `inmetrics`(in vclassification integer, in veditdistance integer,
    in veditgoodness float,
    in vshorternmaelen integer,
    in vspatialdistance float,
    in vspatialprecisiondeg float,
     in vspatialgoodness float,
     in vfeaturetypedistance float,
      in vmetricsid bigint,
      in vchnuniquefeatureid integer,
      in chuniquenameid decimal,
      in vrefuniquefeatureid integer,
      in refuniquenameid decimal,
   in vsetid integer
 )

Comment: BEGIN
  insert into metrics
  (
   classification,
   edit_distance,
   edit_goodness,
   shorter_name_len,
   spatial_distance,
   spatial_precision_deg,
   spatial_goodness,
   feature_type_distance,
   metrics_id,
   ch_unique_feature_id,
   ch_unique_name_id,
   ref_unique_feature_id,
   ref_unique_name_id,
   set_id
  )

Comment: values
   (
    vclassification,
    veditdistance,
    veditgoodness,
    vshorternmaelen,
    vspatialdistance,
    vspatialprecisiondeg,
    vspatialgoodness,
    vfeaturetypedistance,
    vmetricsid,
    vchnuniquefeatureid,
    chuniquenameid,
    vrefuniquefeatureid,
    refuniquenameid,
    vsetid
   );
 END

Comment: there's all the relevant code.  the message is just a stacktrace where that stored procedure call is made.  it's definitely not the C# side of things where things are going bad.

Comment: @Dan: These things are way too complicated to read as comments to my answer. Could you take the time to edit your question to give a readably-formatted treatment of *all* of the relevant information for us to help you. http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: @Dan: How do you know that C# isn't **asking** the database to insert two values with the same primary key of 16777216 (either because you explicitly asked it to, or because of some kind of integer overflow that you weren't careful about.) And without the body of the stored procedure, we can't know if there's some accidental conversion to `MEDIUMINT` happening in the body of the stored procedure.

Comment: The `AUTO_INCREMENT` on `metrics_id` appears to be unused since you're passing in the value as `vmetricsid` in the stored procedure anyway.

Comment: OMG i can't believe it might be something this simple/stupid.  this goes right in the category of having fresh eyes look at something 1 person has been staring at too long.  i'll update if this works...

Comment: how does this help with the comments limits in characters?  thanks